# How to pass a variable to a UIButton action

Tags: ios, uibutton

I want to pass a variable to a UIButton action, for example

```
NSString *string=@"one";
[downbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(action1:string)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and my action function is like:

```
-(void) action1:(NSString *)string{
}
```

However, it returns a syntax error.
How to pass a variable to a UIButton action?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Change it to read:

```
[downbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(action1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I don't know about the Iphone SDK, but the target of a button action probably receives an id (usually named sender).

```
- (void) buttonPress:(id)sender;
```

Within the method call, sender should be the button in your case, allowing you to read properties such as it's name, tag, etc.

Answer (score 18):

If you need to distinguish between multiple buttons, then you could mark your buttons with tags like this:

```
[downbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
downButton.tag = 15;
```

In your action delegate method you can then handle each button according to its previously set tag:

```
(void) buttonPress:(id)sender {
    NSInteger tid = ((UIControl *) sender).tag;
    if (tid == 15) {
        // deal with downButton event here ..
    }
    //...
}
```

UPDATE: sender.tag should be a `NSInteger` instead of a `NSInteger *`

Answer (score 6):

You can use [associative references](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH24-SW3) to add arbitrary data to your UIButton:

```
static char myDataKey;
...
UIButton *myButton = ...
NSString *myData = @"This could be any object type";
objc_setAssociatedObject (myButton, &myDataKey, myData, 
  OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
```

For the policy field (OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN) specify the appropriate policy for your case.
On the action delegate method:

```
(void) buttonPress:(id)sender {
  NSString *myData =
    (NSString *)objc_getAssociatedObject(sender, &myDataKey);
  ...
}
```

Comment: This should be accepted as the right answer.

Note that this requires the following import:

#import <objc/runtime.h>

Besides, the link is broken: as of Nov 2016, the doc is:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/1657527-objective_c_runtime

Answer (score 6):

Another option for passing variables, which I find to be more direct than the tag from leviatan's answer is to pass a string in the accessibilityHint. For example:

```
button.accessibilityHint = [user objectId];
```

Then in the action method of the button:

```
-(void) someAction:(id) sender {
    UIButton *temp = (UIButton*) sender;
    NSString *variable = temp.accessibilityHint;
    // anything you want to do with this variable
}
```

Comment: getting (null)... please suggest me to get exact string.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've found to do this is set an instance variable before calling the action

Answer (score 1):

You can extends UIButton and add a custom property

```
//UIButtonDictionary.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIButtonDictionary : UIButton

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary* attributes;

@end

//UIButtonDictionary.m
#import "UIButtonDictionary.h"

@implementation UIButtonDictionary
@synthesize attributes;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set tag of the button and access it from sender in action

```
[btnHome addTarget:self action:@selector(btnMenuClicked:)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                    btnHome.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                    btnHome.tag = 123;
```

In the called function

```
-(void)btnMenuClicked:(id)sender
{
[sender tag];

    if ([sender tag] == 123) {
        // Do Anything
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the strings of the UIControlStates that you dot'n use:

```
NSString *string=@"one";
[downbutton setTitle:string forState:UIControlStateApplication];
[downbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(action1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and the action function:

```
-(void)action1:(UIButton*)sender{
    NSLog(@"My string: %@",[sender titleForState:UIControlStateApplication]);
}
```