# Adding actions to a button programmatically on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I am trying to add an action to buttons which I am creating programmatically:

```
        [btn    addTarget:self
            action:@selector(indexAction)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This works fine. However, I now want to pass a variable (int k) to the indexAction method. I couldn't get this to work:

```
        [btn    addTarget:self
            action:@selector([self indexAction:k])
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I am sure I'm doing something wrong. This is the context of the above code:

```
  -(void) initIndexButtons {

    float buttonPadding = -8;
    float buttonWidth = 23;
    float buttonHeight = 80;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0,0,0,0);
    for (int k=0;k<5;k++)
    {
        UIButton* btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];;        btn.tag = k;
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, k*(buttonPadding+buttonHeight), buttonWidth, buttonHeight);

        UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"index.png"];
        [btn setBackgroundImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [btn    addTarget:self
                action:@selector(self indexAction:k)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
}

-(void)indexAction:(int *)buttonTag
{
    NSLog(@"buttonTag: %i", buttonTag);
}
```

---

EDIT:

I changed my code to:

```
// ...
[btn    addTarget:self
                action:@selector(indexAction:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        //[self indexAction:k];

        [indexView addSubview:btn];
        [indexView sendSubviewToBack:btn];
    }
}

-(void)indexAction:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger *tid = ((UIControl *) sender).tag;
    NSLog(@"buttonTag: %i", tid);
}
```

But now I get the warning message that "Initialisation makes pointer from integer without a cast for the line `NSInteger *tid = ((UIControl *) sender).tag;`

---

EDIT:

This is the right line of code:

```
NSInteger tid = ((UIControl*)sender).tag;
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you need to find out which button was tapped then you have the tag property which you are already setting to 'k'.

Comment: @onnoweb: Actually, yes, I need to find out which button is tapped. So I thought I assign a 'custom' action to each button, no? How could I check the tag property? My limited aim right now is to have the indexAction method print which button was pressed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The `tag` property is an integer, but the variable that you're assigning it to (`tid`) is declared as a pointer to an integer.  Remove the `*` and it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally the method that a button calls takes one parameter:

```
(id)sender
```

Take a look at the question - [how to pass a variable to a UIButton action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510393/how-to-pass-a-variable-to-a-uibutton-action)

Comment: I had a look at this, but I now get a warning (see above - I've updated my question).

Answer (score 2):

`tag` is an `NSInteger` not `NSInteger*`

change to

```
NSInteger tid = ((UIControl*)sender).tag;
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it is to set:

```
-(void)indexAction:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"Tag=%@"[(UIButton*)sender tag]);
}
```

and the call:

```
    [btn    addTarget:self
            action:@selector(self indexAction:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

not really sure about my casting, haven't tested that, but I think it should work!
Best of luck.