# UITableCell button touchUpInside with index of cell whos button was clicked

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have a UITable with UITableCells which look as the following:

[ myLabel  myButton ]

[ myLabel  myButton ]

[ myLabel  myButton ]

[ myLabel  myButton ]

I would like my handlerCellButtonClicked to also get a reference to the cell index.  How can I get a reference to this index as well when the button is touched?

```c
/** called by table to get the cell needed by the index */
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ...
    //init cell
    ...
    //configure the cells custom button handlers
    [cell.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handlerCellButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}

/** handler when the button in the cell is clicked */
- (void)handlerCellButtonClicked{
    NSLog(@"cell myButton clicked");
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting which UIButton was pressed in a UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802707/detecting-which-uibutton-was-pressed-in-a-uitableview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of `UIButton Tag` property.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    //init cell
    //configure the cells custom button handlers

    cell.myButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handlerCellButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}

/** handler when the button in the cell is clicked */
- (void)handlerCellButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
  {
     NSLog(@"%d cell myButton is clicked", sender.tag);
  }
```

Comment: How are you sure that selector will pass the sender?

Comment: (handlerCellButtonClicked:) should pass the sender to the target, right?

Comment: You can only Pass a (UIButton*) object as a parameter with addTarget @selector method. thats it. Also the "UIControlEventTouchUpInside" event will send the button as parameter.hope you understood.

Comment: @Ramshad: this worked great, adding the colon @selector(handlerCellButtonClicked:)  after the method sends the UIButton and i can get the tag. The problem I have is that if I delete rows the tag is incorrect since the indexs have changed.  But I can post this as another question.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Ramshad does the tag have to be NSInteger or can it be any object?

Comment: @mihai: tag have to be NSInteger however you can pass other datas.this is the answer for your quesion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510393/how-to-pass-a-variable-to-a-uibutton-action

Comment: I think, a tableview reload after a delete will fix your issue. use [myTableView reloadData]; to do this. :) – or create your own logic some think like, if you are deleted the 4th row, then if the button tag is 5, then minus 1 value from it,,,.

Comment: @Ramshad thank you very much! I was able to fix my issue.  Originally i was using the index of the cell to reference the index of the array.  Thats a bad pattern when tag can be anything.  So I made tag be a key in a dictionary and now it doesnt matter the order.  thanks again you were a great help.